# django DateField with year as range

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to store year range like:

```
"1990 - 1991",
"1991 - 1992",
"1992 - 1993",
"1993 - 1994"
```

User can select the appropriate range from the form. But how do I do this.

Comment: I don't understand...First, your dates overlap at one point... and don't at another. Second, a date range is not a valid `DateField` value. My suggestion: just store the end date in the database, but render the form with ranges.

Comment: What value will you store for the first range?

Comment: I want to know if I have to store this kind of information what will be the correct approach???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to store ranges can be done by having two separate date fields, a start date field and an end date field

Or if you are just storing years you might be able to get away with an integer field